# Is it possible to do a two-step initialization of a non-movable object in the member initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to do a two-step initialization of a non-movable object in the member initializer list using C++17?

---

Here is the legacy API I’m working with (and yes I know it’s bad but I can’t change it)

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A(int some_param);

    // no default, move or copy constructor nor assignment
    A() = delete
    A(const& A) = delete;
    A(const&&) = delete;      // it shouldn’t be deleted, but I’m not able to modify that class
    A& operator= (const& A) = delete;
    A& operator= (const&&) = delete;

    // and it uses two phase construction
    void init(int some_other_argument);

    // more stuff
};

class B {
public:
    // no default constructor, and must be created with a fully-initialized A
    B() = delete;
    B(const& A);

    // more stuff
};
```

And here is what I am trying to write:

```cpp
class C {
public:
    C();
private:
    A m_a;
    B m_b;
};

C::C()
    : m_a{ /* two step initialization of A*/}
    , m_b(m_a)
{}
```

---

The usual trick of using a immediately initialize lambda doesn’t work:

```
C::C()
    : m_a{[] {
        auto a = A(0xdead_beef);
        a.init(42);
        return a; // doesn’t compile because A isn’t movable
    }()}
    , m_b(m_a)
{}
```

Nor does using the body of the constructor:

```cpp
C::C()
    // m_a and m_b will be default-initialized here, but their default initializer are deleted
{
    m_a = A(0xdead_beef);
    m_a.init();
    m_b = B(m_a);
}
```

And nor doing the second step of the two step initialization in the body of the constructor:

```cpp
C::C()
    : m_a(0xdead_beef)
    , m_b(m_a) // m_a isn’t fully initialized here
{
    m_a.init();
}
```

---

Currently I’m using a `unique_ptr` for `m_b`, but I was asking myself if there was a better solution.

```cpp
class C {
public:
    C();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> m_a; // guaranted to be initialized in the constructor, no need to check before dereferencing
    B m_b;
};

C::C()
    : m_a{[] {
        auto a = new A(0xdead_beef);
        a->init(42);
        return a;
    }()}
    , m_b(*m_a)
{}
```

---

I think the rules of guaranteed move elision were improved in C++20, but I’m still using C++17.

Comment: `0xdead_beef` ...?  That shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Eljay: `operator""_beef` not shown :)

Comment: *'I think the rules of guaranteed move elision were improved in C++20'* -- Elisions can only happen if move/copy are allowed at the first point.

Comment: Writing a wrapper around `A` with a constructor which calls `init` might be an alternative. `WrapperA::WrapperA(int n1, int n2) : m_a(n1) {m_a.init(n2);}` and `class C {WrapperA m_wa; B m_b; C() : m_wa(0xdead, 42)}, m_b(m_wa.m_a) {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might still abuse of comma operator:

```
C::C() : m_a{ 0xdeadbeef },
         m_b((m_a.init(42), m_a))
{}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn’t expecting that it would even be possible. And what I did is even more cursed but in reality `init()` was returning a bool and if that bool was true the code the I was cleaning was throwing an exception. So I just used a ternary: `m_b(m_a.init(42) ? m_a : throw "error").